# Android Studio 2017 - how to close row under editor tabs

Tags: android, android-studio, androidstudio-settings

How to disable row with tabs under editor tabs (You can see it on the screenshot)?

Row under editor tabs:
[image: Row under editor tabs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Uncheck the option "Show breadcrumbs" -> Apply -> OK